# How do I safely deploy an Excel 2007 Workbook with .net VSTO functionality

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a VSTO Excel workbook that functions correctly in test.  I can deploy the package (publish the solution) but when I distribute it my users are unable to install it.  Any idea, any way to ensure that all necessary install files follow the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb821233(printer).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/cc998641.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937(printer).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at ClickOnce?

http://www.craigbailey.net/screencasts/VSTODeploymentviaClickOnce/VSTODeploymentviaClickOnce.htm